# Как привязать ./gradlew с процессом выполнения android приложения?

Tags: android, linux, отладка, gradle, консоль

Как правило я использую команду на Linux "./gradlew installDebug" для сборки и установки android app. Но эта команда не позволяет отслеживать Exceptins и Error в RunTime режиме. 
Можете помочь командой на Linux которая будет собирать, устанавливать, сохранять в консоли вывода stacktrace? (./gradlew (--stacktrace, --debug) installDebug не справляются с поставленной задачей)

Comment: эм... `./gradlew installDebug && adb logcat > log.txt`?)

Comment: adb - это если не ошибаюсь для эмуляторов? А мне надо для реального устройства

Comment: ошибаетесь... Все логи с андроида читаются только через него.

Comment: Да, спасибо работает. А вы не знаете как фильтровать log-и? А то нужный Exception сложно найти в 17357 строках

Comment: зависит от того что надо. adb logcat поддерживает фильтры. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html тут есть список в блоке "Filtering log output". Если вы работает на линуксе, то я обычно делаю `adb logcat | grep MyApp`

Comment: Cпасибо, очень сильно помогли